# Bunq Developer API exception while creating PSD2 context

Tags: java, sdk

While creating an API context using the bunq Java SDK, I get an exception. I create the API context as follows:

```
ApiContext apiContext = ApiContext.createForPsd2(
            ApiEnvironmentType.SANDBOX,
            SecurityUtils.getCertificateFromFile("cert.pem"),
            SecurityUtils.getPrivateKeyFromFile("key.pem"),
            new Certificate[]{
                    SecurityUtils.getCertificateFromFile("cert.pem")
            },
            API_DEVICE_DESCRIPTION,
            new ArrayList<>()
);
```

And then get the exception below:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.bunq.sdk.exception.BadRequestException: Response id to help bunq debug: 12414de4-f961-4e52-9cfd-e6a53e602b1b. 
 Error message: 
You can have at most 1 active server credentials.
    at com.bunq.sdk.exception.ExceptionFactory.createExceptionForResponse(ExceptionFactory.java:40)
    at com.bunq.sdk.http.ApiClient.createApiExceptionRequestUnsuccessful(ApiClient.java:326)
    at com.bunq.sdk.http.ApiClient.assertResponseSuccess(ApiClient.java:307)
    at com.bunq.sdk.http.ApiClient.createBunqResponseRaw(ApiClient.java:285)
    at com.bunq.sdk.http.ApiClient.post(ApiClient.java:187)
    at com.bunq.sdk.model.core.PaymentServiceProviderCredentialInternal.createWithApiContext(PaymentServiceProviderCredentialInternal.java:54)
    at com.bunq.sdk.model.core.PaymentServiceProviderCredentialInternal.createWithApiContext(PaymentServiceProviderCredentialInternal.java:35)
    at com.bunq.sdk.context.ApiContext.initializePsd2Credential(ApiContext.java:254)
    at com.bunq.sdk.context.ApiContext.createForPsd2(ApiContext.java:159)
    at io.heist.bunq.BunqData.context(BunqData.java:143)
    at io.heist.bunq.BunqData.apiKeys(BunqData.java:115)
    at io.heist.bunq.BunqData.main(BunqData.java:171)
```

Comment: How did you generate your certificate/key?

Answer (score 1):

This likely occurs because you are trying to create an additional `APIContext` using the same certificate/key pair you used to create the first. Try generating a new certificate/key pair:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes -subj '/CN=My App PISP AISP/C=NL'
```

You may first have to delete the `bunq.conf` file that stores the serialized `APIContext`.

If the above still gives you the same error, try changing the country code to another country (e.g., `DE`).

Comment: I resolved this error long back. The problem was -subj. I didnt changed the name

Comment: Ah! Yes, that is why changing the country code also works.